# Online SSH key to Fingerprint conversion

Tags: fingerprint

Is there any tool available in web to convert SSH public key to Fingerprint. Due to circumstances, i cant run ssh-keygen -lf command.

Or is there any option in putty i can use?

Answer (score 4):

This is a very silly way of doing things, but in case you don't find any better answers, you can do the following:

1. Go to [this code snippet](http://ideone.com/JCs08E) on ideone.
2. Click on "edit".
3. On line 6, paste your SSH key.
4. Click on the green "ideone it" button.
5. Your fingerprint will appear in the output box below the code.

---

For posterity, the code (in Python 3) looks like this:

```
# Code from <https://stackoverflow.com/a/6682934/1535629>
import base64, hashlib

# paste your key on line 6
key = """

"""

def lineToFingerprint(line):
    key = base64.b64decode(line.strip().split()[1].encode('ascii'))
    fp_plain = hashlib.md5(key).hexdigest()
    return ':'.join(a+b for a,b in zip(fp_plain[::2], fp_plain[1::2]))

print(lineToFingerprint(key))
```

With credit to [@phihag over on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6682934/1535629).